# Multiple Drupal sites using the same code base

Tags: 7, multi-sites, configuration

Is it possible to use the same Drupal code base for different Drupal sites, just by changing `settings.php` and the database settings, and accessing it through a subdomain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

coleopterist is right.

Let's say you want ***mydomain.com*** and ***sub.mydomain.com*** to share the same codebase, you will have to put two folders in sites/ :

- sites/mydomain.com/
- sites/sub.mydomain.com/

If you want modules and themes to be available to all domains defined in sites/, all you have to do is to put them in all/ :

- sites/all/modules/
- sites/all/themes/

Then, in sites/{domain}/settings.php you can redefine the databases strings like so :

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'database_name',
      'username' => 'user_name',
      'password' => 'p4ssw0rd',
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => 'drupal_',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Note that you should launch the DrupalRoot/install.php script for each different domain to create its database tables.